# How to interact with yopmail OTP using java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to copy OTP from Yopmail using java selenium webdriver but getting this error

Unable to find element with locator By.xpath: `/html/body/main/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/span`

Here is the structure, screenshot below.

Your OTP:  689809

Comment: Please add complete `HTML source` in textual format

Comment: Do not use absolute xpaths at all.